# access aspx.cs page's method in gridpanel store for fetching data in extjs

Tags: asp.net, extjs, grid, json.net

I am working with ExtJs 4.0.I want to access aspx.cs page method to fetch data in extjs gridpanel. 
I tried to find solution from following code but didn't find success.

**grid.js**

```
Ext.application({
    launch: function() {
        // Model definition and remote store (used Ext examples data)
        Ext.define('ForumThread', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['countryId', 'countryName'],
            idProperty: 'countryId'
        });

         var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: 20,
        model: 'ForumThread',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'mindbody.reports/test.aspx/display',
            reader: {                
                type: 'json',
                method: "GET",
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            }
        }
    });

        // Define grid that will automatically restore its selection after store reload
        Ext.define('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        });

        // Create instance of previously defined persistant selection grid panel
        var grid = Ext.create('PersistantSelectionGridPanel', {
            autoscroll: true,
            height: 300,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            //region: 'center',
            store: store,
            multiSelect: true, // Delete this if you only need single row selection
            stateful: true,
            forceFit: true,
            loadMask: false,
            viewConfig: {
                stripeRows: true
            },
            columns:[{
                id: 'countryId',
                text: "countryId",
                dataIndex: 'countryId',
                flex: 1,
                sortable: false
            },{
                text: "countryName",
                dataIndex: 'countryName',
                width: 70,
                align: 'right',
                sortable: true
            } ]
        });
    }
});
```

**test.aspx.cs**

```
public string display()
{
      country obj = new country();
      JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
      return serializer.Serialize(obj.SelectAll());  
}
```

**url: 'mindbody.reports/test.aspx/display'** I am trying to get data from display method of test.aspx page but not getting any data n even no errors. I thing anything wrong in calling method.

Comment: You are missing something. You cannot call page's method from browser. Use web-services (.asmx) instead.

Comment: @Alexey Solonets can i access class's method from browser??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below line of code before your method display() on your test.aspx.cs page

```
  [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
```